JWT token with API Gateway returns unauthorized all the time
I have an axios call using JWT token that works when I call the EC2 instance directly, but when I call it through the API Gateway, it returns:
success:    false
message:    "unauthorized access! no headers!"

here is the nodejs code:
exports.isAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    try {
      const decode = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      const user = await User.findById(decode.userId);
      if (!user) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'unauthorized access!' });
      }

      req.user = user;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'unauthorized access!' });
      }
      if (error.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'sesson expired try sign in!',
        });
      }

      res.res.json({ success: false, message: 'Internal server error!' });
    }
  } else {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'unauthorized access! no headers!' });
  }
};

here is the Reactjs code:
const headers = {
   Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
   authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
};

return axios.get(BE_URI + "/fetch-general-news", { headers });

I did however make sure the API Gateway's endpoint allowed headers, but it looks like the headers are not being forwarded, what am I doing wrong? 

You have a few issues here... 1) GET requests have no body content so why are you setting a content-type header? 2) Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true and Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is an invalid CORS configuration. It will cause issues. 3) Are you sure the Authorization header value is meant to be prefixed with JWT? Typically it's Bearer

well it works when I call the EC2 instance direcly, it's only with API Gateway that it doesn't work, I can try changing Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my specific website

even when setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my specific site, I still get unauthorized access

using Bearer doesn't fix the issue either, it works with direct call to EC2 as well though, I can leave it as Bearer I guess if you think it's better, but it doesn't solve the issue

I only asked if you were sure JWT was the correct prefix. What it should be is entirely up to your API implementation

I added the nodejs code

have you confirmed that a valid token is being sent in the Authorization header

the problem with your server code is, you can't tell which one of two conditions is causing the response

@JaromandaX three conditions

yes, because it works when I call the EC2 instance direcly instead of going through the API Gateway (with same token)

but you are right, I could put more specific error message, pretty sure the problem is that the header is not being forwarded by the API Gateway though

@JaromandaX I made the error message more specific, see edit, it's what I thought, headers not forwarded

you mean that one header, you can't state that no headers are forwarded

How is your isAuth middleware incorporated into your (Express?) API? It could be that you've misconfigured the handler and it's intercepting a preflight OPTIONS request where the Authorization header won't be present

It's the API Gateway that seems to block the headers, since it works if I call the EC2 direcly

I added a console.log for headers, you are right some headers are being passed, but not the one I set : {"x-amzn-apigateway-api-id":"xxxxxxxx","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-667b5ade-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","user-agent":"AmazonAPIGateway_xxxxxxx","accept":"application/json","host":"ec2-xxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000","connection":"Keep-Alive"}

@Phil it works fine If I call the EC2 instance direcly, it's only blocked if I call the API Gateway that links to the EC2 instance, so i'd say it's probly incorporated correcly, really looks like the API Gateway is not forwarding the headers correcly

Humour me and log the req.method

never mind, found the solution, see my answer

Found it! thx for your help guys, so I'll leave the solution in case someone else gets blocked, you need to add the header you want AWS API Gateway to forward in the "Method Request" of your endpoint for it to be forwarded : 

JWT Authorization is supported for HTTP API Gateway. For REST API, you need to use API Gateway Lambda Authorizer.

I found the solution, thx for your attempt, see my answer
